How to Implement a Custom Observer Pattern in Java Without Using Built-in Libraries?
I am trying to implement the Observer design pattern in Java without using built-in libraries like java.util.Observer or PropertyChangeSupport. I want to create a simple system where observers (listeners) can subscribe to a subject and get notified whenever the state of the subject changes.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Subject {
    private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
    private String state;

    public void subscribe(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
        // Notify observers
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
}

class Observer {
    private String name;

    public Observer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void update(String state) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + state);
    }
}



What Did You Try and What Were You Expecting?
I tried iterating over the observers list in the setState method and calling an update method on each observer. I expected the observers to print the updated state, but I am not sure how to link the Subject and Observer classes correctly.
What Actually Happened?
Currently, the program compiles but doesn’t produce the expected output because I haven’t implemented the notification logic.
Expected Result:
I want the Subject class to notify all subscribed observers whenever the state changes, producing the following output:
Observer 1: State Changed!
Observer 2: State Changed!

Let me help you on your problem:
To implement a custom Observer Pattern in Java without using built-in libraries like java.util.Observer or PropertyChangeSupport, we can create a program like below:
Step 1: Define the Observer interface
public interface Observer {
    void update(String message); // Observer gets a notification
}

Step 2: Define the Subject Interface
public interface Subject {
    void registerObserver(Observer observer);  
    void unregisterObserver(Observer observer); 
    void notifyObservers(String message);       
}

Step 3: Implement the ConcreteSubject
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
    
public class ConcreteSubject implements Subject {
    private final List<Observer> observers  = new ArrayList<>(); // List to store observers
    
    @Override
    public void registerObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void unregisterObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(String message) {
        for (Observer observer : observers) {
            observer.update(message); // Notify each observer
        }
    }
}

Step 4: Implement the ConcreteObserver
public class ConcreteObserver implements Observer {
    // A unique identifier for the observer
    private final String name; 

    public ConcreteObserver(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(String message) {
        System.out.println(name + " received update: " + message);
    }
}

And we can test the observer pattern like below:
public class ObserverPatternTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the subject
        ConcreteSubject subject = new ConcreteSubject();
        
        // Create observers
        Observer observer1 = new ConcreteObserver("Observer 1");
        Observer observer2 = new ConcreteObserver("Observer 2");
        Observer observer3 = new ConcreteObserver("Observer 3");
        
        // Register observers
        subject.registerObserver(observer1);
        subject.registerObserver(observer2);
        subject.registerObserver(observer3);
        
        // Notify observers
        System.out.println("State change 1st time.....");
        subject.notifyObservers("First Update");
        
        // Unregister an observer and send another notification
        subject.unregisterObserver(observer2);
        System.out.println("State change 2nd time.....");
        subject.notifyObservers("Second Update");
    }
}

Output:
State change 1st time.....
Observer 1 received update: First Update
Observer 2 received update: First Update
Observer 3 received update: First Update
State change 2nd time.....
Observer 1 received update: Second Update
Observer 3 received update: Second Update


Fix your code formatting and indenting. Otherwise good Answer.

Sure @BasilBourque Thanks for the comment. I am learning how to put proper format.

You’re not done yet. Prose is flush left, no indenting. Code either (a) is indented on every line by four SPACE characters, or (b) has a line before and after consisting of three back-tick characters each, optionally followed on the first line of back-ticks with the name of the programming language.

Sure, I did my best. Thanks.

thanks @ahuemmer for helping in editing.

Your Observer needs to have some action associated with it. When state changes, that action will get triggered.
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        
        new Thread(() -> {
            Observer observer = new Observer(subject, value -> 
                System.out.println("Successfully executed this with value: "+value+" inside thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName())
            );
            try {
                subject.subscribe(observer);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                
            }
        }).start(); 
        
        new Thread(() -> {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                String value = "hello"+i;
                System.out.println("Updating the state to: "+value);
                subject.setState(value);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
class Subject {
    private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
    private String state;

    public void subscribe(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
        observers.forEach(observer -> observer.update(state));
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
}

interface Action{
    
    public void doSomething(String value);
}

class Observer {
    private Action action;
    private Subject subject;

    public Observer(Subject subject, Action action) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void update(String state) {
        // you can log subject or do something else
        action.doSomething(state);
    }
}

